# How to set up Android Dynamic Feature Modules with install-time (not onDemand) properly?

Tags: android

I have an Android game app which size is approximately 300 Mb so I decide to split my resources by dynamic feature module set up with "Include module at install-time". Before uploading, I have used command "bundletool build-apks --bundle xxx.aab --output=xxx.apks" to check output apk files and make sure each of one is below 150 Mb. But I still got the error message below:

**One or more of the auto-generated multi-APKs exceeds the maximum allowed size of 150 MB.


Your App Bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB：ARM64_V8A + HDPI, ARM64_V8A + XHDPI, ARM64_V8A + TVDPI, ARM64_V8A + XXHDPI, ARM64_V8A + LDPI, ARMEABI_V7A + XXXHDPI, ARM64_V8A + MDPI, X86 + XXXHDPI, X86 + HDPI, X86 + XXHDPI**

I have no idea why I still got this message through each of the apk files is bellow 150 Mb? How can I upload my game to Google Play beyond the maximum allowed size? I have read official websites and other posts for many days but most of them are all about setting up with "On-Demand" which is not what I want. What I want is when users download the app from the store and install it successfully then everything is ready to go.

How can I upload my app beyond the maximum size to the store without additional download after the app installed? How to set up dynamic feature modules with install-time properly? Should I use dynamic feature modules to solve this problem or are there any better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Apps like PUBG which exceeds the maximum allowed size on the Play Store don't need additional download process. How can I archive my aab file in this way?